# Regex matching groups of contacts

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I am having problems trying to write a PHP Regex matching pattern to match and split string into needed groups.

Here is the situation... I have a multiple strings with contacts:

`+35 00000000, info@company.com, www.company.com`
This would give me: 
**Group 1:** +35 00000000, info@company.com, [www.company.com](http://www.company.com)

`+35 00000000, +360000000, info@company.com, www.company.com`
This would give me: 
**Group 1:** +35 00000000
**Group 2:** +36 00000000, info@company.com, [www.company.com](http://www.company.com)

`info@company.com, www.company.com`
This would give me: 
**Group 1:** info@company.com, [www.company.com](http://www.company.com)

`+35 00000000, info@company1.com, www.company1.com, +36 00000000, info@company2.com, www.company2.com`
This would give me: 
**Group 1:** +35 00000000, info@company1.com, [www.company1.com](http://www.company1.com)
**Group 2:** +36 00000000, info@company2.com, [www.company2.com](http://www.company2.com)

As you can see, these strings can be different. What I need to do is split those strings into groups of contacts, which:

- often start with phone number (+), but not always and can contain only one
- can start with website link or with email if no phone is provided
- can contain multiple groups of different companies

So at first I tried to match groups starting with phone number and ending with website:

```
((\+?[\d ]+)?(, )?(.*)(, )?(www\.\w+\.\w{2,})?)
```

But this does not match exact. Also then tried to simplify everything ant match groups that start with phone numbers:

```
(\+[\d ]+).*
```

But this matches full strings.

Have to say I'm a big noob regarding Regex. I manage to do basic matchings, but this is too hard for me.

Length of pattern or low performance is not important as this will be a one-time execution.

Comment: Maybe you can just split the string by `, ` then scan the delimited fields? If you can do something without regex, you should go for the solution without regex.

Comment: Try `(?=[^\s,])(\+?\d(?:[\d\s]*\d)?)?(?:(?:,\s*|^)(\S+@\S+)\b)?(?:(?:,\s*|^)(www\.\S+)\b)?`, see  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2YjmBF/1). Or, `(?=[^\s,])(\+?\d(?:[\d\s]*\d)?)?(?:(?:,\s*)?(\S+@\S+)\b)?(?:(?:,\s*)?(www\.\S+)\b)?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/2YjmBF/2))

Comment: @DanielW. This was my first option, but I don't see how I could then match phone number with website without knowing if they are in the same group (like if I have an array of 6 elements).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The second pattern looks extremely promising. Maybe you should consider posting it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the matches with expected groups using

```php
(?=[^\s,])(\+?\d(?:[\d\s]*\d)?)?(?:(?:,\s*)?(\S+@\S+)\b)?(?:(?:,\s*)?(www\.\S+)\b)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2YjmBF/2).

Note that `(?=[^\s,])` lookahead is used to avoid matching empty strings.

*Details*:

- `(?=[^\s,])` - the next char must be a char other than a comma and whitespace
- `(\+?\d(?:[\d\s]*\d)?)?` - an optional Group 1: an optional `+`, a digit, and then an optional occurrence of zero or more digits and whitespaces and then a digit
- `(?:(?:,\s*)?(\S+@\S+)\b)?`  - an optional occurrence of

  - `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional occurrence of a comma and zero or more whitespaces
  - `(\S+@\S+)\b`  - Group 2: one or more non-whitespaces, `@`, one or more non-whitespaces, a word boundary
- `(?:(?:,\s*)?(www\.\S+)\b)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional occurrence of a comma and zero or more whitespaces
  - `(www\.\S+)\b` - Group 3: `www.`, one or more non-whitespaces, word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the matches using:

```
 (?:\+?\d+(?:\h+\d+)*,\h*)?[^\s@]+@[^\s@,]+,\h*www\.\S+|\+?\d+(?:\h+\d+)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\+?\d+(?:\h+\d+)*,\h*)?` Match an optional `+` then digits with optional spaces
- `[^\s@]+@[^\s@,]+` Match an email like pattern only matching a single @
- `,\h*www\.\S+` Match a `,` followed by `www.` and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `|` Or
- `\+?\d+\h*\d+` Match the phone number like pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O4SwrJ/1)

Or matching both ways for the url and the email address using an alternation `|`

```
(?:\+?\d+(?:\h+\d+)*,\h*)?(?:[^\s@]+@[^\s@,]+,\h*www\.\S+|\h*www\.\S+,\h*[^\s@]+@[^\s@,]+)|\+?\d+(?:\h+\d+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vclmRm/1)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. However the accepted answer also solves for the situation when first group ends with website and a second group has only website.